# $f : (0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ countinous with non-negative right-hand derivative is non-decreasing

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f : (0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continous, right-hand derivable, such that $f'_+ \geqslant 0$ $\forall t \in (0,1)$. Show that $f$ is non-decreasing.

First I thought of Lagrange's theorem but I don't think that's useful here. Then, for every $x, y$, I tried to cover $[x, y]$ with a finite number of open subsets $(x_i, x_i+\delta_i)$ such that f was non-decreasing in every one of them, so that I could write $$f(y)-f(x)=f(y)-f(x_n)+f(x_n)-f(x_{n-1})+...-f(x) \geqslant 0$$ but I had no luck there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*"You assume too much"* as several characters in *Star Wars* say.  Some things are easier to prove if you assume less.  In this case the existence of the one-sided derivative is misleading since it encourages you to search for methods appropriate to that.  There is a bit of advice for problem solving that most of us learned from Polya: if there is a problem that you can't solve find a more general (perhaps easier) problem that you can't solve.

The posted solution may look somewhat magical since the definition of the function *g*  there might not have occurred to you.  But what must certainly have occurred to you is to try for a contradiction.  In other words, imagine that there are points  *a < b*  with  *f(a) > f(b)*.  Since  *f*  is continuous there
must be a last point  *c*  before  *b*   where the function does not rise above the line *y = f(a)*.  Just look carefully at the point *c*  where *f(c)=f(a)* and where the function subsequently goes down.

The "last point" argument here is quite ancient. (This is essentially what the other solution does.) It goes back at least to a paper of Dini in 1878.  For that you don't need a positive right-hand derivative --- a positive upper right-hand Dini derivative suffices.  You also don't need it everywhere, you can have a countable set of exceptional points where you don't know this but that is harder to prove.  In fact there is a generalization due to Zygmund where you can assume even less.

The most accessible reference for this and similar ideas is Saks, *Theory of the Integral*, pp.203-204.  This was published in 1937 and so scanned copies can be found on the internet with a bit of searching.

I gather the problem was a homework assignment and the originator is happy enough to solve it and get on with other stuff.  Do remember, however, that this is training for research and that it pays to think deeper about most problems and to pursue the history where possible.

Comment: Tanquam ex ungue leonem !

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help, you're very knowledgeable and I am very happy to learn new methods whenever possible. I did a bit of research before posting this question, however I have not found anything useful. This last point argument looks solid and easy. If I got it right, once you find said point $c$, you conclude because $f'_+ > 0$, but the function is decreasing from $c$ onwards. How would you conclude if you only have $f'_+ \geqslant 0$? Could you resort to the function $g(x)=f(x)+\varepsilon x$ like the above poster suggested?

Comment: Yes, the idea of using $g(x)=f(x)+\epsilon x$ is standard and I expected you to pick it up from the other guy.  When you start doing detailed proofs in analysis like this you might get irritated by the difference between $A>B$ and $A \geq B$.   Always keep the $\epsilon$-trick available  so you can use whatever you want.  You probably already remember that to prove  $c \geq d$ sometimes can only be done by proving that $c+\epsilon > d$ for all $\epsilon>0$.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose first that for all $x$, we have $f_{+}^{\prime}(x)>0$. Then, for all $x\in{]0,1[}$, we have $f(y)>f(x)$ for all $y>x$, close to $x$.

Let $a,b\in (0,1)$, and put $g(x)={\rm Sup}\{f(t), t\in [a,x]\}$ for $a\leq x\leq b$. As $f$ is continuous on the compact $[a,x]$, there exists a $c_x\in [a,x]$ such that $g(x)=f(c_x)$. Suppose that $c_x<x$. Then by the above, there exist $y$, $c_x<y<x$, close to $c_x$, with $f(y)>f(c_x)$, a contradiction with the definition of $c_x$. Hence we have $c_x=x$, and $g(x)=f(x)$. As obviously $g$ is increasing, we have proved that $f$ is increasing on $[a,b]$, and hence on $]0,1[$.

Now if you have only $f_+^{\prime}(x)\geq 0$, replace $f$ by $f(x)+\varepsilon x$, ($\varepsilon>0$) this function is increasing by what we have said above,  and let $\varepsilon \to 0$.

Comment: In the first proof (with $f'_+(x) \gt 0$), does '*increasing*' mean '*weakly increasing*'? It seems like we should be able to say '*strictly increasing*', yes?

Answer (score 3):

For *differentiable* functions this is a direct consequence of the mean-value theorem, which in turn is a consequence of Rolle's theorem.

In our case, where $f$ is only assumed to have a (nonnegative) right derivative at every point in the interval, one can mimic the proofs of these theorems as follows:

For $0 < a < b < 1$ consider the function
$$
 g(x) = f(x) - \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}(x-a) 
$$
which is right-differentiable with
$$
g_+'(x) = f_+'(x) - \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} \, .
$$
$g$ attains its maximum on the interval $[a, b]$ at some point $x_0$, and since $g(a) = g(b)$ we can assume that $a \le x_0 < b$. Then $g_+'(x_0) \le 0$, so that
$$
 \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} = f_+'(x_0)- g_+'(x_0) \ge 0
$$
and therefore $f(b) \ge f(a)$, i.e. $f$ is non-decreasing.

*Remark:* If $f_+'$ is strictly positive on the interval then the same proof shows that $f$ is strictly increasing.

Comment: Is there any greater meaning to these functions? Or do the functions merely 'serve our logical purposes'? It seems like this set up lets us compare the instantaneous rate of change to the average rate of change and find strategic instances (e.g. at the max) where one must be greater than or equal to the other

Comment: If that is correct, why do I need to define $g$ with the property that $g(a)=g(b)$? Isn't the proof valid if I describe $g$ as:  $g(x)=f(x)-\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}(x-c)$ for any arbitrary $c$?

Comment: Ahhh, I see why. If $b$ (but *not* also $a$) is the maximum point on $[a,b]$,  $g'_+(b) \leq 0$ cannot be guaranteed. Cheers~

Comment: @S.Cramer: $g(x) = f(x) - L(x)$ where  the *linear* function $L$ is chosen that $g(a) = g(b)$. It is  the same construction as in proofs of the mean-value theorem, e.g. here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Proof

Comment: Sure - I recognized the function. I guess I mostly just wanted to understand how this particular function was *identified* (discovered) as being one that would be helpful for our purposes. What would have initially led someone in to suspecting that $g(x)=f(x)-L(x)$ would be *useful* for the purposes of this proof? When I see clever functions like this employed in proofs, I always wonder what the initial motivation (intuition) was for their usage.

Comment: @S.Cramer: It is easier to see in the proof of the MVT: If $f(a) = f(b)$ then Rolle's theorem gives $f'(\xi) = 0$ for some $\xi \in (a, b)$. The general case is reduced to this special case by considering $g(x) = f(x) - L(x)$ for a suitable linear function $L$. – I took the same approach here, only that Rolle's theorem can not be applied directly ($f$ is not differentiable), but we still can use that $g$ attains its maximum and make conclusions about the right (or left) derivative at that point.

Answer (score 2):

Of course *methods* are more important than *answers* so I hope you will indulge another answer to this problem. Our *amico appassionato* who posted the question suggested a method that he couldn't make work. But the idea was fine and the idea does work if you persist.

We assume that the continuous function $f$ has a positive right-hand derivative at each point (or even just a positive upper right Dini derivative). We fix $ x < y$  and want to conclude that $f(y)>f(x)$.

Set $x_0=x$ and choose $x_{n}<x_{n+1}<y$ so that $f(x_1)>f(x_0)$, 
$f(x_2)>f(x_1)$, $f(x_3)>f(x_2)$, $\dots$ inductively.

[This is more or less exactly what the poster had in mind.]

Define $x_\omega$
as the limit of the sequence $\{x_n\}$.
Unfortunately $x_\omega$ may not be $y$ but at least, using continuity,
we know that $f(x_\omega)>f(x)$.  Just keep on going.  This will require transfinite induction but in a countable number of steps you will certainly reach $y$.

The intervals $[x_\alpha, x_{\alpha+1}]$ form what is known as a *Lebesgue chain* and solve the problem much in the way that the poster thought might work.  The only extra idea needed was to drop the hope that it could be done in a finite number of steps.  This method used to be rather popular long ago.  Is it still taught?

[Added: Oh, by the way, the hope for a *finite* number of intervals (instead of a countable number as here) should have disappeared pretty fast when you realize that you haven't then any need for continuity.  But a simple counterexample would show the problem doesn't work without continuity or some similar assumption.]

Comment: Hello, 
thank you for your answer. I really like this method, and I think i "got" what we are trying to do here. However, I had never heard of transfinite induction before. Is there a way of formalizing the last passage without too much trouble ("This will require transfinite induction but in a countable number of steps you will certainly reach y.")? 
(I did realize I had to use continuity in some way but I couldn't figure it out.)

Comment: Also, what if $f'_+ \geqslant 0$ (and not $>0$) like in this case?

Comment: You will learn about transfinite ordinals later on.  I wanted to validate your instincts.  Basically your idea could be described as, starting from $x$, produce a sequence of points that ends at $y$  so that the values of the function $f$ increase along the sequence.  If you pursue this idea you find that you can make some progress towards $y$ but just not get all the way.  Well keep going.  You might think that a sequence of such attempts succeeds. The apparatus of transfinite ordinals rescues the idea.  But pursuing this idea was useful and might  have led to the "last point" argument.