# Prove that $\sup_{(a, b)} f’_{-} (x) \geq 0 \geq \inf_{(a, b)} f’_{-}(x) $

Tags: derivatives, proof-writing

Function $f$ is continuous on $[a, b]$ and has a $f’_{-}$ on $(a, b)$. $f(a) = f(b)$, then show that
$$\sup_{(a, b)} f’_{-}(x) \geq 0 \geq \inf_{(a, b)} f’_{-}(x) $$

Here’s my attempt.
Consider 2 cases:

1. $f$ is constant, then the statement is obvious.
2. $f$ is not a constant. Since $f$ is continuous, there is a minimum $m$ and maximum $M$ on $[a, b]$. Then $m = f(x_1)$, $M = f(x_2)$. If both $x$s are in $(a, b)$, the statement is proven, because $f’_{-}(x_1) \leq 0, f’_{-}(x_2) \geq 0$.
   I don’t know what to do if only one of the $x$s lies in $(a, b)$. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: It is shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3844594/42969) that if the one-sided derivative is strictly positive on the open interval then the function is strictly increasing.